# What is the meaning of "Not actually"?

Tags: american-english, questions, spoken-english, negation

For example, let's say Person A says "1 plus 1 is 3". Then Person B can either say "It's not 3, it's 2" or "It's actually 2".

What if Person B says "It's not actually 3, it's 2"? Does the negation "not" apply to "actually" or "3"? As far as I know, it's supposed to apply to "actually". If true, what does it mean exactly? And will the meaning change if you swap "not" and "actually"?

Answer (score 1):

*Actually* (in fact) qualifies the statement "It's not 3".

> Actually, it's not 3.
>
> It's actually not 3.
>
> It's not actually 3.

all mean the same. I find what B said the least logical way of expressing it, but this order of words is commonly used in casual speech.

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean exactly by "qualifies"? Does the statement become stronger or weaker?

Comment: It's a form of emphasis. It makes the statement stronger,  contradicting what may have been thought. It underlines the whole proposition. If it's negated as "not actually" the scope is the same: the whole statement. It's definitely 2, it's definitely not 3.

Comment: @JackO'Flaherty Regarding what Kate said, it should also apply if I replaced "actually" with "really" right? Given that both words are synonymous.

Comment: @Max It's about the same, but it has a different tone. To me, "actually" is politely presenting what the speaker thinks may be new to the hearer; "really" may be less carefully polite and more insistent.

Comment: You could also replace it with _In fact/As a matter of fact_.